# Copy value from Input and select into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with *input[text]*, *select* and *textarea*, **How to clone or copy data/value** of *input(type=text), select, textarea* in a div or span, in other words in HTML.

And it must happen without refreshing or reloading the page. In other words if I type something in:
`<input type="text" name="f_name" value="Small john" />`

I want to see the text "Small john" in a

`<span id="first_name">{here is the value of the field name}</span>`

or if I Select a option form a select list and this option has a value of id "499" and its content is "USA", then i want USA to be displayed ina span, for example with id="Country_name".

I guess its all done with ***jquery/JS***. So i made this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rKv2q/)**, for those who would like to give a try!

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Well, yeah thanks for your point! I gues u r happy now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$("input[name=f_name]").on('keyup', function () {
    $('#first_name').html($(this).val());
});
$("select[name=country]").on('change', function () {
    $('#Country_name').html($(this).find('option:selected').text());
});
```

Use

- `$(this).find('option:selected').text()` if you want to select text
- `$(this).find('option:selected').val()` if you want to select value

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HZ3t7/3/)

Comment: Yeah but it copies all values from the select list, an not the selected one. I am poor with JS and have no idea how to fix.. If you can then please, thanks anyway for your huge help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#first_name').html($('input[name=f_name]').val());
    $('#Country_name').html($('select[name=country] option:selected').text());
});
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WLZyn/1/)**

This `$('input[name=f_name]').val()` gets the value of the input.
This `.text()` gets the text of the selected option.
This `.val()` gets the value of the selected option.

Answer (score 0):

Sergio was on the right track. Unfortunately, he didn't quite test his solution. This one works...

http://jsfiddle.net/WLZyn/2

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#first_name').html($('input[name=f_name]').val());
    $('#Country_name').html($('select[name=country] option:selected').text());
});
```

So, in fact (for some truly odd reasons), this...

`$('select[name=country] option:selected').text()`

gets the text of the selected option

`$('select[name=country]').val()`

gets the value of the selected option